# How to find generator matrix given a PCM of a Hamming code?

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, coding-theory

I'm having trouble as how to begin solving this. I'm given a Hamming Parity Check Matrix, and I have to find code vector V and generator matrix G.

H = \begin{bmatrix}
0&0&1&1&0&1&1\\
0&1&0&1&1&0&1\\
1&0&0&0&0&1&1
\end{bmatrix}

Any explanation would be most welcome, mostly on the Generator matrix part. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you mean $\begin{bmatrix}
0&0&1&1&0&1&1\\
0&1&0&1&1&0&1\\
1&0&0&0&{\color{red}1}&1&1
\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: A matrix H should not have equal columns (that's probably how  Snowball detected that you've made a typo).

Comment: I've checked the problem, but I've copied exactly as it is written. Is there any chance it is not H, but something else?

Comment: Hint: $GH^T = \mathbf 0$. When $H$ has a _block structure_ such as $H= \left[I \mid P\right]$, so does $G$. Can you figure out what $G$ must be?

Comment: Thanks for your help, I got it right now.